# Replace part of a compound string using MySQL 5.5

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I need to replace part of a compound string.

List of compound strings:

```
+-------+---------------------------------+
| cod   | ub                              |
+-------+---------------------------------|
| 1642  |NORMAN|BATES|RO|Eserc|CAR|(Ex: ) |
| 1641  |Marion|Crane|VR|Eserc|RET|(Ex: ) |
| 1640  |Lila  |Crane|RO|Eserc|PLS|(Ex: ) |
| 1639  |Sam   |Looms|RO|Eserc|CAR|(Ex: ) |
| 1638  |Milton|Arbog|VR|Eserc|CAR|(Ex: ) |
+-------+---------------------------------+
...
```

I want to replace the fifth element in each serialised record.

This string for example

```
"NORMAN|BATES|RO|Eserc|CAR|(Ex: )"
```

On this case, I need replace the value of the string from **"CAR"** to

```
"FOO"
```

For this return

```
"NORMAN|BATES|RO|Eserc|FOO|(Ex: )"
```

I have tried using an SELECT SQL query [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tyq9UeXea6vReMTwaMawW3/2)

```
SELECT 
REPLACE(
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
"NORMAN|BATES|RO|Eserc|CAR|(Ex: )"
,"|", 2)
,"|", -1),
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
"NORMAN|BATES|RO|Eserc|CAR|(Ex: )"
,"|", 2)
,"|", -1), "FOO") x;
```

And I have this output.

```
+-----+
| x   |
+-----+
| FOO |
+-----+
1 row in set (0.10 sec)
```

But in query UPDATE SQL the whole string is replaced by the value "FOO"

```
UPDATE `tbl_d` 
SET Ub = REPLACE(
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
"NORMAN|BATES|RO|Eserc|CAR|(Ex: )"
,"|", 2)
,"|", -1),
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
"NORMAN|BATES|RO|Eserc|CAR|(Ex: )"
,"|", 2)
,"|", -1), "FOO") WHERE Cod = "1642";
```

Any help really appreciated.

```
NORMAN|BATES|RO|Eserc|FOO|(Ex: )
```

Comment: Why not just `SELECT REPLACE('NORMAN|BATES|RO|Eserc|CAR|(Ex: )', '|CAR|', '|FOO|');`?

Comment: ?why all the substringing? surely a simple replace would do? as in replace ('NORMAN|BATES|RO|Eserc|CAR|(Ex: )','CAR','FOO')

Comment: @P.Salmon because the string is not always CAR... the string is an example....

Comment: @user1191247 because the string is not always CAR... the string is an example.

Comment: I don't get it - you want to pass a string, change an unknown value in the fifth token to an unknown value? Have you oversimplified?

Comment: This is why you shouldn't put delimited lists in columns. Normalize your tables and this will be easier.

Comment: Your question is still unclear. Do you mean, you want to replace the fifth element in each serialised record?

Comment: @user1191247 yes Sir, I want to replace the fifth element in each serialised record

Comment: Where are these compound strings coming from? And why are you setting and resetting every ub value in the update WHERE Cod = "1642";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps substring_index might work for you

```
select   concat(
            substring_index('NORMAN|BATES|RO|Eserc|CAR|(Ex: )','|',4) ,
            '|FOO|',
            substring_index('NORMAN|BATES|RO|Eserc|CAR|(Ex: )','|',-1)
            ) aa;

+----------------------------------+
| aa                               |
+----------------------------------+
| NORMAN|BATES|RO|Eserc|FOO|(Ex: ) |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```